# navigate into wrong tab when refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that has two main tabs, devices and reports. Every time I refresh the page, the page display the information for reports(suppose to display the info for the devices). This also applies when I double the html file directly or use window.location =url.

sample js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#mainpage').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = "main.html";

      });
    });
```

What are the possible reasons?

Comment: Can you share your Javascript?

Comment: Can you show more code. A fiddle will be a good way. As I understat you use jquery, or not? Anyway a little of CSS will alsobe nice from your side!

Comment: Thanks, uploaded codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reload a page, the style and css of your tags are not hold, it is just like you entered on it for the first time. So if you reload a page like this you can't keep the current status of your page.

Since your question is very generic, I'll give you two ideas of how to solve it, and you are on your own to learn about it.

- **Option 1**: Send a get parameter along with the url and when refreshing the page display the right div
- **Option 2**: Reload what is necessary with an AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks. I added ?show=devices after the link. it worked. So I only have to fix reload.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing with fotanus' suggestions in her answer, you could also:

- **Option 3**: use a cookie to record the page state in case of a page reload
- **Option 4**: use two interlinked pages, one for each tab.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I never thought in the number 3